# calling function inside a function in requirejs module javascript

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Hi guys is this posibble? calling a function inside  a function inside a requirejs module? TIA

```
define([
'common'
], function(Common) {

return {
    func1: function() {
        return 'this is function 1';
    },

    func2 : function (data){
        console.log(func1);

    }
};
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code as stated won't work.  I suggest changing it to something like this:

```
define([
'common'
], function(Common) {

    var exports = {};

    var func1 = exports.func1 = function() {
        return 'this is function 1';
    };

    var func2 = exports.func2 = function (data){
        console.log(func1);
    };

    // A function that is not exported but can be accessed from other code in this module.
    var privateFunc = function() {
    };

    return exports;
});
```

I personally think this style of code is clean and flexible.  It is clear which functions are being exported, and they can reference each other using simple, local variable names.

Comment: thanks @cspotcode. but with this implementation "privateFunc" cannot be called other modules

Comment: @koko Also you can use `func1`, `func2` which is the functions returns by themodule. But internally in the module you can use `func1`, `func2`

Answer (score 0):

Lets split a requireJs module in its part to understand what happens:

Let requireJs know that this is a module

```
define(
```

Some dependencies

```
[ 'common'],
```

So this is the main part. After all this just a function that is called when loaded. RequireJs save the result of the function and inject it in every module that has this module as dependencies

```
function(Common) {
  return
```

So this is what every module get when it require this module

```
{
    func1: function() {
        return 'this is function 1';
    },

    func2 : function (data){
        console.log(func1);

    }
  };
```

So in your case you return just a simple object with to 2 functions as it members.

What you try to do cant work cause there is no `func` in the scope, aka the function that returns the object.
But a there is member `func` in your object, so you can call `this.func1`.

You can also have a function in your function like this:

```
define([
'common'
], function(Common) {

  function func1() {
    return 'this is function 1';
  }
  return {
    func2 : function (data){
        console.log(func1);
    }
  };
});
```

But then `func1` isn't accessible from outside

Answer (score 0):

Inspired on Andreas Köberle answer I found this work-arround, but Im almost sure there are a better way to do that...

```
define(function(require) {

  function func1() {
    return 'this is function 1';
  }
  return {
    func1: function() {
      return func1();
    },
    func2 : function (data){
        console.log(func1);
    }
  };
});
```

This way we can access from inside and outside the method func1. For me works very well.
Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

The follwing would work...

```
console.log(this.func1());
```

You haven't specified the handle correctly, 
you have to use `this` to specify the func1 handle.
and i think you were about to call `func1()` to print `'this is function 1'` 
not just do `func1` without paranthesis, as it would print the function definition.