# Node.js - Expose Functions Within a Module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a code snippet below

```
g = function() {
    require(["game"], function(b) {
    ...
    }
}
```

How would I go about exposing everything within `game`? I'm using RequireJS if that helps?

If I do If I do `window.b= b;` and try to access `b.functionWithin()` I get the error `functionWithin not a function`

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287537/calling-function-inside-a-function-in-requirejs-module-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Everything exported from that module is assigned to `b`, in your example.